# how to install an ssl certificate on my Windows Server?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, ssl

I am trying to get HTTPS to work on my AWS Lightsail instance

I searched and read a lot... but I never find a resource based on my need

1. I have a VPS (not shared hosting), specifically it's a AWS Lightsail instance
2. it has Win Server, most instructions are for linux
3. I need it to be free
4. I am using XAMPP
5. I am not looking for Wordpress, MyBB, etc... I am looking for sth. for all of the Apache (XAMPP) server

Comment: You could use Certbot (free software) with free Let's Encrypt certificates https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=other&os=windows

Comment: first, you should have CSR provided by Godaddy or Namecheap and then you can generate SSL from CSR using your windows server, then import it on Windows Server using IIS.
https://qawithexperts.com/article/technology/generate-csr-and-import-ssl-on-iis-windows-server/396

Answer (score 0):

The way to install SSL/TLS certificates is the same for your case (XAMPP) as it is in Linux. The paths differ, but you should add the certificate in Apache config.

If you need to install it in Windows itself the procedure is:

- Enter Start | Run | MMC.
- Click File | Add/Remove Snap-in .
- In the Add or Remove Snap-ins window, select Certificates and click
  Add.
- Select the Computer account radio button when prompted and click
  Next.
- Select Local computer (selected by default) and click Finish.
- Back in the Add or Remove Snap-ins window, click OK.
- In the MMC main console, click on the plus (+) symbol to expand the
  Certificate snap-in.
- Navigate to Personal | Certificates pane.
- Right-click within the Certificates panel and click All Tasks |
  Import to start the Certificate Import Wizard.
- Follow the wizard to import the signed certificate along with the
  private key. The certificate file must be in a container format
  having both the end user certificate and its private key.

For more information you can check [here](https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/how-can-i-import-certificates-into-the-ms-windows-local-machine-certificate-store/170504615105398/).